# string that matches nth position of substring of array and show value of this array

Tags: php

if i have one string is

```
$str = "CD";
```

than,
it will found only 3rd and 4th position below array string and fetch that array value,

```
$arr = ["ABCDE", "BCDEF", "BACDF","ACDLK"];
```

its output will be like below,

```
$arr = ["ABCDE", "BACDF"];
```

is it possible?

Comment: *is it possible?* - yes.

Comment: How can you please explain it? -@NigelRen

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Can you please explain on what logic you want to filter the elements from `$arr`? It makes no sense to me

Comment: Start by writing the code to match the value your after (`$str`) in a single string, once this works create a loop to work over an array.

Comment: @Amfasis If I understood right, he wants to filter `$arr`'s items when they contains `$str` at a specific position in the string.

Comment: `array_filter()` + `strpos()`. That's all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to achieve what you want as below,

```
$arr    = ["ABCDE", "BCDEF", "BACDF", "ACDLK"];
$findme = "CD";
$result = [];
array_walk($arr, function ($mystring) use (&$result, $findme) {
    // check if string contains and its position index 0 means 1
    // and so on
    if (strpos($mystring, $findme) == 2) { 
        $result[] = $mystring;
    }
});
print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABCDE
    [1] => BACDF
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ada3e1fa865a811a71346f691c008758c9944e8f).

Comment: Not sure if something like `ABDCDE` should work, but this will select it.

Comment: Yes, because criteria is not mentioning to check other letters except `CD`, right?

Comment: I thought the CD had to be the 3rd and 4th characters, it's the 4th & 5th in the above example.

Comment: Ohh, Yes. I made changes in answer, you can check now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that too

```
 $arr    = ["ABCDE", "BCDEF", "BACDF", "ACDLK"];
    $result = [];
    $search = "CD"; 
    function Search($search, $string){ 
        $position = stripos($string, $search, 2);   
        if ($position == true){ 
            return true; 
        } 
        else{ 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
    foreach($arr as $key){
      if(Search($search, $key)){
         $result[] = $key;
        }
    } 
    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `strpos()` you have to be careful that the string your looking for isn't in the string before the position your looking for.

So `CDCDE` will give 0 for `strpos()` when looking for `CD` and so may reject the string due to it not being in the right position.

A simple alternative is to use `substr()` to extract the characters you want to check and compare that to the string your after.  I've parameterized it so that it's easy to change...

```
$arr = ["ABCDE", "BCDEF", "BACDF", "ACDLK","ABDCDE", "CDCDE"];
$str = "CD";
$strLen = strlen($str);
$position = 2;
$result = [];
foreach( $arr as $string )  {
    if (substr($string, $position, $strLen) == $str) {
        $result[] = $string;
    }
};
print_r($result);
```

will give...

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABCDE
    [1] => BACDF
    [2] => CDCDE
)
```